# How to update the number of childs?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has this fields:

```
ID
IDParent
NumberOfChilds
```

It is a table that has a field to know the number of childs that a row has. I NumberOfChilds is a new field, so I need to update it with the correct value. I am trying a query like this:

```
update MyTable
set NumberOfChilds = (select count(t.ID)
                      from MyTable as t
                      where t.IDParent = ID
                     )
```

But this query set 0 to all the rows no matter if a row has childs or not. How could I set the new field with the correct value?

Comment: If the hierarchy has arbitrary depth, you may need to use a recursive CTE here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the subquery. 
Correct query should be:

```
Update MyTable 
set NumberOfChilds = (select count(t.ID) 
from MyTable as t 
where t.IDParent = MyTable.ID)
```

Comment: Remember to explain *why* your query is correct and the OP is not.  It is not immediately obvious what you are doing here and why, especially for a new SQL user.

Comment: @iamdave You are right. I tried to find the best way to explain it and I think the guy in the following link gives an excellent explanation https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162414/correlated-sub-query-on-the-same-table-with-only-one-alias

Answer (score 3):

You aren't relating the outmost table `MyTable` with the correlated subquery (which is now not correlated at all), so there is no row that has a `ParentID` equal to it's own `ID`, and returns 0 for all rows.

You can fix this with a simple CTE or subquery:

```
;WITH Counts AS
(
    SELECT
        M.ID,
        AmountOfChildren = COUNT(1)
    FROM
        MyTable AS M
        INNER JOIN MyTable AS C ON M.IDParent = M.ID
    GROUP BY
        M.ID
)
Update M set 
    NumberOfChilds = ISNULL(C.AmountOfChildren, 0)
FROM
    MyTable AS M
    LEFT JOIN Counts AS C ON M.ID = C.ID
```

---

However, if you want to traverse relationships and count all children of children this gets a little more complex as you need to traverse recursively all children relationships to know how many levels down it goes.

Set up:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (
    ID INT,
    IDParent INT,
    NumberOfChilds INT)

INSERT INTO @MyTable (ID, IDParent)
VALUES 
    (1, NULL),
    (2, NULL),

    (3, 1),
    (4, 1),
    (5, 2),

    (6, 4),
    (7, 4),
    (8, 7),
    (9, 7),
    (10, 9)
```

Update:

```
;WITH RecursiveCTE AS
(
    -- Anchor
    SELECT
        StartingID = M.ID,
        CurrentID = M.ID,
        Level = 0
    FROM
        @MyTable AS M

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursion
    SELECT
        StartingID = R.StartingID,
        CurrentID = M.ID,
        Level = R.Level + 1
    FROM
        RecursiveCTE AS R
        INNER JOIN @MyTable AS M ON M.IDParent = R.CurrentID
),
MaxLevelByID AS
(
    SELECT
        R.StartingID,
        NumberOfChilds = COUNT(DISTINCT(R.CurrentID)) - 1 -- Don't count self
    FROM
        RecursiveCTE AS R
    GROUP BY
        R.StartingID
)
UPDATE L SET
    NumberOfChilds = M.NumberOfChilds
FROM
    @MyTable AS L
    INNER JOIN MaxLevelByID AS M ON L.ID = M.StartingID
```

Result:

```
ID  IDParent    NumberOfChilds
1   NULL        7
2   NULL        1
3   1           0
4   1           5
5   2           0
6   4           0
7   4           3
8   7           0
9   7           1
10  9           0
```

I strongly suggest **not** to store this value as it is computed and it will need a refresh on each insert, update or delete of *any* record. You should calculate this on-demand (with a view or whenever you need to use it), rather than keeping it stored.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
UPDATE mt
     SET mt.NumberOfChilds = mt1.NumberOfChilds 
FROM MyTable mt CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfChilds 
      FROM MyTable mt1
      WHERE mt1.IDParent = mt.id
     ) mt1
WHERE mt.IDParent IS NULL;
```

This assumes when `ID` has `null` IDParent  then it considered as `Parent`. So, just filter-out it & do update operation.